# Cannot access js object methods from an event handler

Tags: javascript, html, object, eventhandler

This HTML snippet creates an Object prototype, instantiates it, then unsuccessfully tries to use that object's methods from an Event.

```
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="TestLogic()">Test Logic</button>
    <script>
        function onOff() //Object prototype
        {
            this.state = false;

            function setState(newState) {
                this.state = newState;
            }
        }
        var inputOne = new onOff(); //Instantiate object prototype
        function TestLogic() //buttonClick Event Handler
        {
            inputOne.setState(true);
            // generates Uncaught Type Error undefined is not a function */
            document.inputOne.setState(true);
            // generates Uncaught Type Error Cannot read property setState of undefined 
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: document.inputOne should be just inputOne and " function setState" should be "this.setState= function setState"

Comment: `setState` is local to `onOff`. You never expose it to be called from the outside. Neither is `inputOne` a property of the `document` object. I recommend to read http://quirksmode.org/js/contents.html to get a better understanding of JavaScript and how it works in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The function in `onOff` is private, it's not being published as a public property. Change `function setState(newState) { ... }` to `this.setState = function(newState) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstanding about javascript contexts. MDN has good [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about it. See comments to know where you was wrong:

```
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="TestLogic()">Test Logic</button>
    <script>
        function onOff() //Object prototype
        {
            this.state = false;

            //set method to context of creating Object
            this.setState = function (newState) {
                this.state = newState;
            }
        }
        var inputOne = new onOff(); //Instantiate object prototype
        function TestLogic() //buttonClick Event Handler
        {
            inputOne.setState(true);
            //document is not a scope, window is global scope
            window.inputOne.setState(true);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
 <body>
<button type="button" onclick="TestLogic()">Test Logic</button>
<script>
    function onOff() //Object prototype
    {
        this.state = false;

         this.setState=function(newState) 
         {
            this.state = newState;
            console.log(this.state);
         }
    }
    var inputOne = new onOff();
    function TestLogic()
    {
        inputOne.setState(true);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the OP seems to be a beginner, explaining what was wrong with their code and how/why your solution solves it would be very valuable to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use prototypes then use prototypes like this

```
function Object () {
    this.instanceMethod = false;
}
Object.prototype.prototypeMethod = function () {};
```

Also you should avoid using inline event listeners and do it like this instead

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
// logic
});
```

And here is an example of it all used together (http://jsfiddle.net/sAH35/)

```
<body>
    <button type="button">Test Logic 1</button>
    <button type="button">Test Logic 2</button>
    <button type="button">Test Logic 3</button>
    <script>
        //Object prototype
        function OnOff(element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.state = false;
        }
        OnOff.prototype.setState = function (newState) {
            this.state = newState;

            if (this.state) {
                this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            } else {
                this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
            }
        };

        // bind to elements
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('button');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                if (!this.onOff) this.onOff = new OnOff(this);
                this.onOff.setState(!this.onOff.state);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Since the OP seems to be a beginner, explaining what was wrong with their code and how/why your solution solves it would be very valuable to them.